# order item cancel through api

Tags: magento-1.7, api, sales-order

I want to attempt to cancel order for a specific order item through api. Magento get permission to cancel order by **increment id** of an order through **API**.As Example :

My order id : **10000001**

Order items ids are **23,45**

Now I want to cancel order for item id **45**.

Its possible or not?? Please any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot cancel/delete one item from an existing order but you can create a credit memo for this item.

Check out the `sales_order_creditmemo.create` method from the [Magento SOAP API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrderCreditMemo/salesOrderCreditMemo.html).